# Call a class's function template with function pointers as parameters

Tags: c++

I'd want to use a function pointer in my template argument list. I do miss something of B even I am writing `int` in full main of both `A` and `B`. I have a class `X.h` like so, don't know which one it is now causing the error.

```
struct X
{
  int fun(int a)
    {
        return a;
    }

    template<typename A, typename B>
    A func(int x, B(*f)(int))
    {
        A i = 10;
        return i + f(x);
    }
};
```

and I like to use it in `main.cpp`

```
int main()
{
    X d;    
    std::cout << d.func<int, int>(10, &X::fun) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The error is `No instance of func matches the argument list...`

Comment: Pointer to nonstatic member function are not actually pointers. They're very different from pointer to free functions.

Comment: `&X::fun` has type `int (X::*)(int)` not `int(*)(int)`. There is no conversion from the former to the latter.

Comment: The type of `&X::fun` is `int (X::*)(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that the argument `&X::fun` is of type `int (X::*)(int)` while the parameter `f` is of type `int(*)(int)` (when B = int) and there is *no implicit conversion* from the former to the latter and hence the error.

To **solve** this you can change the parameter `f` to be of type `B(X::*)(int)` as shown below. Note that the syntax for making a call using member function pointer is different for making a call to a free function.

With C++17, we can use `std::invoke`.

```
struct X
{
  int fun(int a)
    {
        return a;
    }

    template<typename A, typename B>
//------------------vvvv-------------->added this X:: here
    A func(int x, B(X::*f)(int))
    {
        A i = 10;
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvv-------->this is the syntax to call using member function pointer
        return i + (this->*f)(x);

       
       //return std::invoke(f, this, x);  //use std::invoke with C++17
    }
};
int main()
{
    X d;    
    std::cout << d.func<int, int>(10, &X::fun) << "\n"; //works now
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ETv9sE7Ec)